# How to select a ReactJS component in CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to set some CSS values to some ReactJS components.

Is there a way to access the components by their component?

Imagine this ReactJS component:

```
import './assets/css/custom.css'

<Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark" sticky="top" className="navbar-custom-main">
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
      <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
        <Nav className="mx-auto justify-content-center ">
          <Nav.Link href="#features" clas>Home</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Little Do you Know</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="#pricing">My Work</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Resume</Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
```

How can I set the font color for `Nav.Link` part using CSS?

I tried this in my `custom.css`:

```
Nav Nav.Link {
color: "red"  !important;
}
```

And it doesn't work. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: You already have className then use it.. e.g `.navbar-custom-main {}` or you can inpect element to check the dom node.

Comment: @HarishSharma, no this class is assigned to the `Navbar` and doubtfully it doesn't work for the tags under it. But if I add class to every Link it works. I don't want to copy paste class in every Nav.Link

Comment: for NavLinks you can use `.navbar-custom-main .nav-link {}`

Comment: @HarishSharma how did you guess/find this `.nav-link` name?

Comment: @JananthBanuka: It lists the class of `.nav-link` at the source for the documentation page I linked in my answer, https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navs/#nav-link-props  See: `<a href="/home" data-rb-event-key="/home" class="nav-link active">Active</a>`  This is not a long-term solution.  You have no idea whether that package will change its classes, or if someone on your team adds a similarly named class.

Comment: @JananathBanuka I just inspect the elements via. chrome dev tool. I know you are using `react-bootstrap` Navbar component.

Comment: Thank you for the documentation. Can I get this class name for every bootstrap component ?

Comment: Yes, you can.. just learn to inspect elements. Finding class name will be a peace of cake for you. :) Adding my answer below.. you can accept it as you answer..

Comment: Hi, JananthBanuka: Yes, you can use a single className for multiple components.  That is why we use classes.

Answer (score 1):

Is Nav.Link a component you have written?

If you have written the component edit the code of the component instead of style it from outside with a class and nested CSS selectors.

If the component is imported from a library and you want to edit it (without editing node_modules files) you can inspect the HTML elements the Nav.Link component is rendering. It could have CSS classes you can modify with your custom CSS.

Other option that I use with Ant Design library, which can be a little tricky to style, is Styled Components, making a custom component which wraps the library component with a styled-components div, style it as needed and importing my custom component instead of the library one.

Answer (score 0):

> Give the component `id` or `class` and just add css to that `id/class`

---

Example:

`<Nav.Link className={'active'} href="#features" clas>Home</Nav.Link>`

`.active: {color: red;}`

Answer (score 0):

[`<Nav.Link>`](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navs/#nav-link-props) components are actually rendered just as a combination of `<div/>` and `<a class="nav-link"/>` elements, you can tell if you inspect your element.  So, `Nav` and `Nav.Link` CSS selectors certainly won't hit these components.

Ideally, give your component an id, or a class and set the CSS...

```
<Nav.Link href="#pricing" id="orange">Resume</Nav.Link>
#orange { color: "orange" };
```

Or:

```
<Nav.Link href="#pricing" className="orange">Resume</Nav.Link>
.orange { color: "orange" };
```

Or, if that doesn't work, you can do it brute force way...

```
style = { color: "orange" };
<Nav.Link href="#pricing" style="{style}">Resume</Nav.Link>
```

The first approach is recommended, because it is scalable and easier to develop with.

Comment: But I have to do this to every `Nav.Link` which is a time consuming work if I have more nav links.

Comment: @JananathBanuka: If you give all your elements you want affected the same class, that should reduce the issue.  Then your new nav links would just be a copy/paste with the same old class each time?  `<Nav.Link className="orangeclass">`, right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to inspect element to find class name where you want to apply css.

In your case, `React-bootstrap` <Nav.Link> component has `nav-link` class:

```css
.navbar-custom-main .nav-link {
 ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also use Ctrl F...
Find Nav.Link...
Replace Nav.Link className="orange"...

You can find all instances and replace them all easily. Hope this helps:)

Comment: Hi, Stephen!  Welcome to SO!  Where did you get `className="orange"`?  I literally made that up as an example for my answer.

Comment: I read thru all the answers before replying. I was going to write the same thing as you but then I thought sometimes the best solution is the simplest. - cheers-